# React show error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating input as div contentEditable and I am setting condition to render child content inside div but I getting the error when entering text to the div:

> NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to
> be removed is not a child of this node.

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

const handleChange = e => {
   setText(e.target.textContent)
}

<div
     contentEditable={true}
     onInput={handleChange}
     suppressContentEditableWarning
>
   <div>{!text ? <br /> : <p>{text}</p>}</div>
</div>
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I solved this error by added `<br />` inside `<div>` element like this:

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

const handleChange = e => {
   setText(e.target.textContent)
}

<div
     contentEditable={true}
     onInput={handleChange}
     suppressContentEditableWarning
>
   <div>{!text ? <div><br /></div> : <p>{text}</p>}</div>
</div>
```